# "make: *** no rule to make target 'all' Eclipse Error

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I have read many threads about this problem, but I was not able to solve it.

I'm running on Linux, with Eclipse and CDT plugin installed.
I have an existing C project, located in /home/luca/prova.
In this folder there are some source files and a makefile (called makefile), that I report below:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -O2
HEADERS = lz78_compressor.h lz78_decompressor.h 
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE = lz78


.PHONY : clean install uninstall help


%.o : %.c $(HEADERS)
    @$(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)


$(EXECUTABLE) : $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
    @echo "Build finished. Executable file created : $(EXECUTABLE)"

clean : 
    rm -f $(EXECUTABLE) $(OBJ)


install :
    -@cp ./$(EXECUTABLE) /usr/bin
    @echo "Tool installed"


uninstall :
    -@rm /usr/bin/$(EXECUTABLE)
    @echo "Tool uninstalled"


help :
    @echo
    @echo "Makefile"
    @echo
    @echo "make                     : build all"
    @echo "install          : install the tool in the system"
    @echo "uninstall        : remove the tool from the system"
    @echo "clean            : remove all .o files and the executable file"
    @echo
```

If I compile in the shell, it works all fine. But I want to import it in Eclipse.
Following this wiki, http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fgetting_started%2Fcdt_w_import.htm
I create a new C project, then I modify settings about the project building.
In the next image there are the settings that I set:

[image]

When I try to build the project, I see the error

```
"make: *** no rule to make target 'all'
```

Why? Anyone could help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an `all` target in your *Makefile*.

### Option 1

Try adding this as a line to tell make what to do when `make all` is done:

```
all: $(EXECUTABLE)
```

### Option 2

You can add extra Make rules with the [Make Target View](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_make_targets_view.htm?cp=7_4_0_4) in Eclipse CDT.

Comment: Thanks, I solved using your option 1: using Eclipse now I correctly compile.
But using make all from the shell, I see this error, why?

lz78 
make: lz78: Command not found
make: *** [makefile:53: all] Error 127

Comment: Please post a new question (don't edit this one) showing your full makefile and your input and output in the shell.